# Prove that Heaviside's function H(x) is a solution for equation

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Prove that Heaviside's function H(x) is a solution for equation

$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_1\partial x_2}=0
$$
$$$$
$$$$
For example, to solve that function

$$ F(x)=e^{2x}H(x)$$

is solution for equation
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-2=0
$$

I should show

$$ F'(x)-2F(x)=\delta_0$$

But how should I prove the first example, where I have mixed derivative?

Thank you in advance

$$$$$$$$
Edit:

I've started:

$$ [H(x_1,x_2)]''[\Phi]=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} H(x_1,x_2)\Phi(x_1,x_2)dx_1dx_2=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\Phi(x_1,x_2)dx_1dx_2=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(0,x_2)dx_2$$

But here I've stoped, what next?

Comment: I think you probably meant to use `\partial` ($\partial$) instead of $\delta$.

Comment: Have you had a try?

Comment: See my edit, please